# Multiple individual 2d rotation at once

Tags: python, numpy

I've a set of (n) geometrical shapes that are defined by a fixed number (p) of 2D points. Those shapes are independent but for efficiency reason, I stored time in a single numpy array. Scaling or translating those shapes are easy, but I would like to rotate them and I'm not sure how to do that. I suspect `np.tensordot` is my friend but I can't find the way to properly use it.

```
n = 100 # Number of shape
p = 4   # Points per shape
P = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (n, p, 2))

# Scaling
S = 0.5*np.ones(n)
P *= S

# Translating
T = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (n, 1, 2))
P += T

# Rotating
A = np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi, n)
cosA, sinA = np.cos(A), np.sin(A)

R = np.empty((n,2,2))
R[:,0,0] = cosA
R[:,1,0] = sinA
R[:,0,1] = -sinA
R[:,1,1] = cosA

np.tensordot(P, R, axes=???)
```

Comment: What would be the shape of the output array?

Comment: The shape should be the same as P (each point of P is rotated)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are keeping the first axis between the two arrays -  `P` and  `R` aligned and `sum-reducing` one each off the remaining axes from the input arrays. So, we can use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) as it will allow us the axis-alignment criteria.

You are using the last axis from `P` for the sum-reduction. Now, depending on which axis of `R` you are losing with `sum-reduction` for the rotation calculation, one of these should do the job -

```
np.einsum('ijk,ilk->ijl',P,R) # Using last dim of R for sum-reduction
np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl',P,R) # Using second dim of R for sum-reduction
```

Comment: Thanks ! What would be the geometrical interpretation between the first and last option ?

Comment: @NicolasRougier Well I can help you with the code part, not sure about the geometry as it relates here. So, I can't comment on it, sorry.

Comment: I'll experiment then. Thanks again.